# pipedrive api using cURL

Tags: php, curl

hi please help on how to get Deals using cURL.

```html
if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }
  $api_token = 'token-here';
 
// Deal title and Organization ID
 
$Url = 'https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=' . $api_token;
//$Url = 'http://www.example.org/';

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();
 
    // Now set some options (most are optional)
 //$Url = 'http://www.example.org/';
    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);
 
    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");
 
    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");
 
    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 
    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
 
    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
 
    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);
 echo $Url;
    var_dump($output);
```

got an issue not getting a result from Pipedrive using there API Url. no errors on cURL too. but if 'http://www.example.org/' as $Url then it will show results.

Comment: for simple url api call use [`file_get_contents('url')`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_get_contents.asp) instead of curl `file_get_contents('https://api.pipedrive.com/v1/deals?api_token=' . $api_token)`

Comment: yes that's one option however i also need to post fields in pipedrive. i already followed there document here https://pipedrive.readme.io/v1.0/docs/creating-a-deal but no luck.

Comment: got an curl error message "error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version"

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366429/php-curl-error-on-ssl-page

Comment: thanks 04FS and prasanth.